# Find minimum distance between unique pairs of nonunique elements in list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, set, complexity-theory

(not homework)

I have a list with repeating elements: `A B C B A D C B`

I want the shortest distance between every two unordered elements:

```
(A B): 1
(A C): 2
(A D): 1
(B C): 1
(B D): 2
(C D): 1
```

Can I improve the complexity of my current implementation? Elements are words and the search space is paragraphs, so I expect ~100 unique elements in lists of length ~200.

My implementation:

```
pairs <= map(pair, distance)

   For each unique element 'me'
1. \  For each index 'o'  of me in list
2.    \  For each 'item' at index 'i' in the list
         |  if (item == me) skip
         |  pair <= sort(me, item)
         |  distance <= abs(i - o)
         |  existing <= dist(pair in pairs), or infinity
         \  if (distance < existing) pairs <= (pair, distance)
```

I don't like it because

1. requires an `O(u•n)` search for indexing occurrences of unique items
2. is `O(u•o•(n-o))` with `u` and `o` being unique items and their occurrences

With a sample text blob that's:

1. `74500` checks for occurrences
2. `250000` comparisons for skipping
3. `247582` sort pair, hash, get from map, compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler and faster algorithm.  Assume the list is in the array X[]:

- Initialise a 2D array best[i][j] to contain INF for all 1 <= i < j <= u.
- Initialise an array last[i] to contain -INF for all 1 <= i <= u.
- For each position i:

  - For each element type j:

    - If j != X[i]:

      - Let x = min(j, X[i]) and y = max(j, X[i]).
      - If i - last[j] < best[x][y] then update best[x][y] to i - last[j].
  - Set last[X[i]] = i.

This has space complexity O(u^2), which is minimal, and time complexity O(u^2 + un), which I suspect is also minimal.

**[EDIT: As requested, we now report just the minimum distance between a pair of elements in "either direction" instead of separately in both directions.  Also added a u^2 term to the time complexity in case n < u, though it sounds like we are guaranteed that n >= u from the underlying problem.]**

Comment: Awesome! You beat me with a 70% reduction in iterations. The typical case is 25% better than O(u^2+un), too. Thanks! Did you already know the solution or did it just occur to you quickly?

Comment: It just seemed like it couldn't be "harder" than the maximum subarray problem, which is solvable in linear time with Kadane's algorithm.  I tried to think of what would be necessary to keep track of if we could only look at each array item once.  Glad it's helpful :)

Comment: BTW I'm not too sure what you mean by "25% better than O(u^2+un)"...  Such an algorithm would also be O(u^2+un).

Comment: Sorry, I just mean that it short circuits for 25% of the input and so avoids doing any actual work for part of that. Missing "easy" things like Kadane's algorithm is what happens when you lack formal education, I guess  :(

Comment: Oh, I don't think Kadane's algorithm is easy *to think of*!  It's pretty clever because it does a lot in not much time, which is why I remember it :)